# Symfony form event POST_SUBMIT

Tags: forms, symfony, events

I'm trying to understand how event listeners in symfony forms actually work. I tried different things and I really don't know where I'm wrong...

Here's my form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
            'class'        => User::class,
            'label'        => 'User',
            'choice_label' => 'email',
            'attr'         => ['class' => 'form-control']
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Select',
            'attr'  => ['class' => 'btn-primary btn-block']
        ]);
    $builder->get('user')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            dump($event->getData());
            dump($event->getForm());
        });
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([]);
}
```

My guess was that it would dump me some data whenever I submitted the form but it's not dumping anything.

I tried changing the event type but only PRE_SET_DATA and POST_SET_DATA is dumping informations (null for $event->getData() though)...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be so nice and take a minute or two and transcribe the contents of your screenshot and provide it as text. Rationale can be found at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question.

Answer (score 0):

You must add event for form builder.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
    dump($event->getData());
    dump($event->getForm());
});
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunatly it didn't change anything...